# Clicking links in a Google Form

Tags: python, selenium, google-forms

I would like to click a variable number of links on a webpage using a Python script. 
I created a simple Google Form for testing, you can have a look [here](https://forms.gle/GemqcBUqsV2ZmMS99). 
In this example, I want to click on every "Python" link and perform some other operation on each page. 
I wrote some code but it doesn't work right now. 
In my code LIST_SITE is the URL I provided above.

```
filesInDirectory = getFilesInDirectory()
for i in filesInDirectory:

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    driver.get(LIST_SITE)
    time.sleep(1.5)

    links = driver.find_elements("xpath", "//a[@id='mG61Hd']")
    hrefs=[]
    for link in links:
        hrefs.append(link.get_attribute("href"))
        print('Link: ' + link)
        print('hrefs: ' + hrefs)

    for href in hrefs:
        print('href: ' + href)
        linkToClick = driver.get(href)
        linkToClick.click()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Do you have any suggestions? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you check with this `xpath`  `//div[@class='OxAavc']`- instead of `xpath", "//a[@id='mG61Hd']`

Comment: @EminentEmperorPenguin What is your error? Please show the stack trace

Comment: @TalAngel it shows no errors, it just opens the URL provided without clicking anything and then it closes the window

Comment: @Akzy now I have an error: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "WebElement") to str` when I try to print `link`

Comment: @EminentEmperorPenguin - The Error message is very clear, You can only concatenate string not the WebElement.